# Recursively implementing a copy constructor for linked list implementation java

Tags: java, list, recursion

How would you recursively implement a copy constructor for a functional linked list?
I am confused because I need to use the copy constructor in my add method, but then I would need to use my add method in my copy constructor which seems a bit tangled.
Thoughts?

Comment: what have you tried so far. I would recommend adding some code to your question

Comment: why would you need to use the copy constructor in add method?

Comment: because it is a functional linked list, so if I add to it, I need to return a deep copy of the list with the new object added, leaving the original as it was

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use copying-add in copy- constructor.

```
public MyList(List<? extends T> list) {
    for (T item : list)
        This.addWithoutCopy(item);
}

MyList<T> add(T item) {
    MyList<T> copy = new MyList<T>(this);
    copy.addWithoutCopy(item);
    return copy;
}
```